# Tightening a threaded coupling near a soldered joint

Tags: plumbing

I tightened a threaded couple and then soldered a 3/4" connection. Despite using Teflon tape and applying about 20 lbs of torque, there is a very small leak. Should I melt the connection and tighten while hot or put in a new compression fitting so I can turn to tighten?

Comment: Normally you'd sweat the fitting first, allow the parts to cool, then thread it in. You may have melted the tape. Are you able to do that instead?

Comment: The pipe I sweated to was already fixed. I added a pressure regulator with screw fittings on both ends. Now that I think about it, I might be able to turn the whole regulator by 180° if the bottom threads cooperate.

Comment: You can't have a situation where you can't turn a thread, not least, you might need to tighten it.  In iron pipe, the correct answer would be to install a union.

Comment: I was told by the valve manufacturer that the lead-free brass metal used makes overtightening a higher risk to cracking. Your suggestion is heeded; a new compression union is the best route, with new/more Teflon tape.